# RoR linkedin gem & OAuth::Problem (signature_invalid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, rubygems, linkedin-api

I am using Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.8, Linkdin 0.1.7, Roxml 3.1.5 and Oauth 0.3.6. In my accounts controller I am testing the code by Will Read (http://pivotallabs.com/users/will/blog/articles/1096-linkedin-gem-for-a-web-app). When I click "Ok I'll Allow it" button on linkdin, it lands on callback method and then crashes on this line:

`atoken, asecret = client.authorize_from_request(session[:rtoken], session[:rsecret], pin)`

with the following error trace:

`OAuth::Problem (signature_invalid):`

`` oauth (0.3.6) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:167:in `request' ``

`` oauth (0.3.6) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:183:in `token_request' ``

`` oauth (0.3.6) lib/oauth/tokens/request_token.rb:18:in `get_access_token' ``

`` linkedin (0.1.7) lib/linked_in/client.rb:35:in `authorize_from_request' ``

`` app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:52:in `callback' ``

`.....`

Moreover, I checked the values of session for rtoken and rsecret and params[:oauth_verifier], and none of them was blank!

Comment: Did you replace "your_api_key", "your_secret" with real values?

Comment: Dammm, one of the greatest `blunder` I have ever made! Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case the problem was that my consumer sent the request to an HTTP Uri. But the OAuth Server (Stash) had a redirect to httpS. As soon I changed the site url to HTTPS it worked for me.

Another reason can be that there is an Proxy in between. That needs some extra configuration.